# Is [HttpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync] method guaranteed to read the full Content?

Tags: c#, .net, http, asynchronous, stream

There isn't much documentation around it.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasbytearrayasync(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasbytearrayasync%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

If it does not guarantee that the whole Content how do I know when to stop reading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't tell it when to stop reading. It returns a `Task<byte[]>`. So, after some amount of time, it will either

- finish reading the entire body and then give it to you as a single `byte[]`, or
- encounter a problem and throw an exception.

If no exception is thrown, it has successfully read the entire body as a `byte[]`.