# Serialization/De-serialization of Excel file being passed from Angular client to be stored in directory by WCF

Tags: c#, angularjs, wcf, serialization, upload

I have a requirement that I have to upload a file from client to server. The way code is structured as follows

1) A client end coded in Angular. See controller code below

```
function controller($scope, $http, $upload, AppModel, WebFunctionService) {

        $scope.UploadCFTCFiles = function (evt) {


            var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var files = document.getElementById('updCftcFileUploader').files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                var file = files[i];
                if (file) {
                    alert("Name: " + file.name + "\n" + "Last Modified Date :" + file.lastModifiedDate);
                    formData.append("CftcUploads", file);
                    client.open("post", "/Apps/DTCC/UploadCftcFiles", true);
                    client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
                    client.send(formData);  /* Send to server */
                }
            }
}
```

2) Backend server side code which receives the file from client serializes it and send it over to the WCF service.

```
[Route("UploadCFTCFiles")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void UploadCftcFiles(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        var buffer = request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        _client.UploadCftcFiles(stream);
    }
```

Not sure if I am doing it the right way. But I can see the request header at server side and can the the data does come over. The "_client" reference is the instance for WCF service.

[image: Code break showing data being present in request header]

3) WCF service which receives the file stream,  deserializes it and saves it in a given directory

```
public bool UploadCftcFiles(Stream stream)
    {
        // upload the file to "//uscserver/cftcdata/datadumps here"
        return false;
    }
```

I have managed to complete the first bit in terms of passing the file from client end Angular code to server side code. Kind of stuck at step 2. Can anyone please help. Overall architecture of the application as follows

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use ReadAsByteArrayAsync in your code. It's not guarantee that content will be read full when method completes. You need to wait for the task to complete. Try this:

```
[Route("UploadCFTCFiles")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void UploadCftcFiles(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        var task = request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        task.Wait();
        var buffer = task.Result;
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        _client.UploadCftcFiles(stream);
    }
```

See the following link for explanation: [Is [HttpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync] method guaranteed to read the full Content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245169/is-httpcontent-readasbytearrayasync-method-guaranteed-to-read-the-full-content)

Comment: That would solve the issue of passing the data to WCF service. But how would I be able to de-serialize it back to Excel file to be saved as a file on the server

Comment: The safest way to communicate between remote instances are strings, as they more cross-platform compatible. You can use Base64 encode/decode. On sending end you use `System.Convert.ToBase64String` method to convert byte stream to Base64 string, on receiving end you'll use `System.Convert.FromBase64String` method to get your bytes back.